# How to make whole <li> element as a link?

Tags: html, css

I am unable to make whole li element clickable. I tried display properties, but nothing really helped. Here is a code:

```css
#top_menu ul li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

#top_menu ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 14px;
  margin: 6px 0;
  line-height: 28px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

#top_menu ul li:hover>a {
  color: #8fde62;
}

#top_menu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  background: rgba(70, 70, 70, 0.7);
}

#top_menu ul li:hover>ul {
  opacity: 1;
}

#top_menu ul ul li {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}

#top_menu ul li:hover>ul li {
  height: 36px;
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 0;
}

#top_menu ul ul li a {
  padding: 4px 0 4px;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #353539;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Additional</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Commands</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Guides</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And here is the result (on the left of the list there is blank space-not active):

[image]

So what am I doing wrong? How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2):

The padding on the left is caused by the `<ul>`. If you set it to `padding: 0;`, that'll remove the null-space and allow you to style as desired from the `<li>` or the `<a>`

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/6jbwnLy5/)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confusing the issue a bit. The `<a>` can take up as much space inside the `<li>` as you want.

What I think you are missing is lists by default get styled with margin and also padding on the side, you can just remove that:

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, `a` can fill the entire space available within `li`. Here's a working example though I had to adjust your colors and `html` for the snippet to work.

```css
body{background: black;}
#top_menu ul li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

#top_menu ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 14px;
  margin: 6px 0;
  line-height: 28px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

#top_menu ul li:hover>a {
  color: #8fde62;
}

#top_menu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  background: rgba(70, 70, 70, 0.7);
}

#top_menu ul li:hover>ul {
  opacity: 1;
}

#top_menu ul ul li {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#top_menu ul li:hover>ul li {
  height: 36px;
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 0;
}

#top_menu ul ul li a {
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #353539;
}
```

```html
<div id="top_menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Additional</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Commands</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Guides</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo will need to use either javascript or jquery in order to attach an event to the whole li element.
If you decide for jquery you will need to add a class or id to identify the li you are targeting then, you will need to attach it the corresponding event.

```
$( "#top_menu ul li" ).click(function() {
    alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

More informacion at: https://api.jquery.com/click/